# Tab bar in Chrome browser

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4, chrome-for-android

I have a Galaxy S4. I use Chrome browser. Anytime I play with an Android tablet, Chrome has a tab bar like on a desktop OS. I want to enable this on my phone, but I can't find an option to enable it. I tried looking into the prefences file but didn't see anything pertaining to this. Is there a way to enable this? I'm rooted, and don't mind messing around so I don't mind if there's a "hackish" way to do this.

It seems like Chrome is a universal app, so I don't see why it acts different on a phone versus a tablet. Or at least provide an otion for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yet to find a way for chrome without installing a tablet ui rom. Boat browser has this feature. After initial install it will dissapear if you scroll down the page. If you go to settings and lab, just tick the top option to show nav bar.

Dolphin browser also allows this but used too much battery and ran more sluggish to be worth it.

I dont understand why chrome doesnt allow it. Im on a note 1. Its a deal breaker browser feature for me.